# "Not a COM32R image" error when trying to install from a USB key

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

```
Not a COM32R image
boot
```

This is the message that the console infinitely spits out when I try to install Ubuntu 10.04 from a USB. I created the USB using StartupDiskCreator in 11.04.

What is the reason for this behavior? What do I do to set it right?

I have carefully followed the steps listed in the [Ubuntu Install from USB page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download).

Answer (score 118, accepted):

A quick/dirty way to solve this issue is to press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, the computer will provide a text menu with your options, i.e. `live live-install test` etc.

Now just type the option you want, i.e. `live` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will boot it as a Live CD [sic], and then continue installation from there.

Comment: Helped with same error while installing esxi7 on bare metal. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into the exact same problem. I followed the answer posted by 'Lelouch Lamperouge' and can make one small change, I did not have the 'live' command or option to boot from, but instead where it said `boot:` I typed `install` and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

This started the installer normally and I did not have any further problems.

I'm not sure why this comes up, I can imagine it is a problem with how the bootloader is installed (but I could be wrong). Either way this worked for me. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in any way but I do make USB boot drives for my company and what I use is Unetbootin.

The reason I use Unetbootin rather than startup disk creator is that I have noticed that certain computers have issues with startup disk creator's way of preparing the USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when making a boot image on windows for an ovm 3.03 install using Unetbootin. I switched to Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.9.0 and scrolled all the way to the bottom of the linux distro pulldown and selected the "old syslinux" option. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

So I have no idea why this is error occurs but I can add something to this:

I created a boot stick to install Ubuntu on a newer and a pretty old notebook.

On the newer one I could choose to boot in UEFI mode. This did work!

The older one however does not have UEFI so I had to follow the above instructions.

So either the boot stick got created in a way that makes it only work on UEFI properly, or UEFI can handle the issue by itself.