# Ubuntu 16.04 final not booting from stick: gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image

Tags: boot, usb, 16.04

The brand new 16.04 final does not boot from USB stick:

```
Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path
gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image
boot :
```

I made a boot stick with Startup Disk Creator on 14.04 LTS on a Lenovo laptop. 
I repeated this process on another computer (Gigabyte Brix) with a another 16.04 image (downloaded from another location) and a different USB stick. Also this computer didn't boot.


Upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS is probably the most common scenario. How on earth did this get through beta testing??


Edit: in 14.04 LTS there was a similar issue: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS live USB boot error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486602/ubuntu-14-04-lts-live-usb-boot-error-gfxboot-c32not-a-valid-com32r-image?rq=1)

Answer (score 79):

Press TAB when that happens (when you boot and the error message appears) and then you will be able to choose between options (live, live-install, ...). Type live, press ENTER and it will boot you into the live try from there you can install.

I just did it last night.
Some kind of systemUSB issue, no idea.

Comment: same thing is happening on dell optiplex  760, i pressed tab and typed live but system hang. also, the keyboard and mouse were not responsive.

Comment: Works for me too, although the error itself does not inspire my confidence in Ubuntu.  But here I go with the install!

Comment: With 14.04 this step worked for me, but then a kernel panic appeared which I could work around by activating a certain boot parameter (don't remember which but it's easy to try them out again).  When I now use this workaround here in 16.04 (<tab>, live, enter), the system hangs indefinitely with a blinking cursor.  I guess the boot parameter is still needed but I have no chance of entering it, right?

Comment: when I enter `live` I get `Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)`... made this stick with usb-creator-gtk (aka startup disk creator) in 14.04

Answer (score 4):

I made a bootable stick of Ubuntu 16.04, then locked the stick, since there is a hacker trying to close me down. When I tried to boot with this stick, the same thing happened as above, that is, I got the message:
gfxboot.c32 - not a COM32R image.
I went to this site and I did:
“Press TAB when that happens (when you boot and the error message appears) and then you will be able to choose between options (live, live-install, ...). Type live, press ENTER and it will boot you into the live try from there you can install.”
After I see on the screen:
“live live-install check memtest hd mainmenu help: boot:”
Then I typed live, and hit enter.
Even though is seems that the “system hang. also, the keyboard and mouse were not responsive.” Ubuntu live is being loaded, but you do not see it on  the screen. Wait for 2-3 minutes, and finally Ubuntu 16.04 live will come up on the screen OK.
Even though I have a BA in mathematics, I am not a computer geek like you guys. This was just by chance that this worked out OK.