# Problems booting the 16.04 live from USB stick

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb, live-usb

I downloaded the 16.04.1 amd64.iso file and made a bootable usb stick using the program available in my Ubuntu 12.04 desktop.

But when I try to boot from that pendrive comes an error the prevent it from booting.

It says:

```
Missing parameter in cofiguration file. Keyword: path
gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image
boot:
```

And the last two lines are replicating and replicating, on and on...

Anybody can tell me wich configuration file I must correct and how?

Thank you.
Gil

{UPDATE}
I used a Virtual Machine with the 16.04 installed and made my bootable usb stick from there and it is working very fine!
Thank you every one!
Gil

Answer (score 0):

They explain the issue and the fixes in these posts:

[Ubuntu 16.04 final not booting from stick: gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760406/ubuntu-16-04-final-not-booting-from-stick-gfxboot-c32-not-a-com32r-image)

[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS live USB boot error (gfxboot.c32:not a valid COM32R image)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486602/ubuntu-14-04-lts-live-usb-boot-error-gfxboot-c32not-a-valid-com32r-image?rq=1)

Edit:

Here is a short version of the answer (more info in the links):

Type hit `[TAB]` to reveal the boot options. Then, type the option you want and hit enter. For example, type `live` and hit `[ENTER]` to boot the live image.

And, here is the best answer in my opinion:

https://askubuntu.com/a/746412/595992

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.