# Ubuntu 16.04 not booting from USB stick: gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb

The 16.04 ISO does not boot from USB stick. I get the following error:

```
Missing parameter in configuration file. Keyword: path
gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image
boot :
```

I made a boot stick with Startup Disk Creator on 14.04 LTS on a HP Pavillion laptop. I tried the solutions on these posts without success:

[Ubuntu 16.04 final not booting from stick: gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760406/ubuntu-16-04-final-not-booting-from-stick-gfxboot-c32-not-a-com32r-image)

[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS live USB boot error (gfxboot.c32:not a valid COM32R image)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486602/ubuntu-14-04-lts-live-usb-boot-error-gfxboot-c32not-a-valid-com32r-image?rq=1)

When I type any of the options revealed by `[TAB]` after the `boot:` prompt and hit `[ENTER]`, the computer reboots. I tried: `live`, `live-install`, `check` and `hd`. After rebooting, the `boot:` prompt appears again. Also, the prompt keeps getting printed to screen every few seconds if I don't do anything.

Edit:

The ISO might have been corrupted. Re-downloading it in a Windows PC and making the USB there solved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [bug 1325801](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1325801).  The wrong version of syslinux gets used, the one from the running system instead of the one from the ISO.  If you have a runnable 16.04 live system, you can use it to make another one with Startup Disk Creator, or just use mkusb on the 14.04 system, which will give you a safer way to use dd, which works too.

Comment: The explanation for that bug is in one of the links I posted. However, the workaround for that bug did not work for me. I think it was a corrupted ISO. In any case, making the USB in another system worked.

Comment: now I made the stick with 16.04 ubuntu desktop on 16.04 lubuntu desktop, on boot the screen splashes with usual purple and man-icon then I get `uncompression error -- System halted`...

Comment: if I quickly press enter during the purple screen it goes to usual menu with "Try ubuntu/install/memcheck" etc options. But on "install" I get `Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)` -- there are several disks in the system, maybe it randomly picks up one of them.