# Loop when installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb, hp

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 from a live install USB drive onto an old "HP Pavillion Entertainment PC" (I think it's from ~2008).

In the installation wizard I get through the "Welcome", "Preparing to install Ubuntu" and "Installation type" pages without any obvious trouble, just picking the defaults all the way along. This brings me to the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" page, with an "Install Now" button. When I click this button, it spins for a moment, and then the heading in the window changes from back to "Installation type". The rest of the window contents do not change, and the "Install Now" button is still there. If I click on it a second time, I'm sent back to the actual "Installation type" page! I tried a few times but seem to be stuck in a loop.

I've used the exact same USB drive to install on another machine, and I verified that the image was not corrupt after I downloaded it.

I did also run into [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/q/760406/2583) earlier in the process, but used the proposed solution on that page to get around it.

How do I get past this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the installer was somehow getting tripped up because of an existing installation of Linux Mint on the machine. I wanted to completely wipe out this installation, so this is what I did from within the Ubuntu "live" environment before running the installer:

**Note that following these instructions will cause permanent data loss.**

1. Ran `lvscan` to find the existing logical volumes.
2. Ran `lvremove` on each of the logical volumes returned by `lvscan`.
3. Ran `gparted` and  deleted all of the partitions from the hard drive.

**Again, following these instructions will cause permanent data loss.**

Once this was done I started the installer which worked correctly.