# Ubuntu 16.04 installation stuck before installation starts

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, live-usb, usb-installation

I have been using ubuntu systems for over a year now. And have installed and reinstalled it multiple time in this interim.

However, right now I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and am wanting install 16.04 (something I have done in the past on this computer)

I have created a bootable USB drive using Startup Disk Creator. It says the installation was successful. But:

```
The usb did not change names to 'Ubuntu...' after creating the bootable drive.
```

Anyway, as it said there had been no problem, I continued. Rebooted my computer, Selected de USB from the bootMenu. Then was prompted in a black screen if I wanted to try ubuntu without installing or install it. I chose to install it. Up to this point all is fine and well.

```
At this stage the installation process should begin, but it doesn't. 
It just hangs on the "Desktop" screen without ever starting the installation.
```

Here is how it looks

[Hangs on This screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUU1N.jpg)

I think could be a problem with the usb stick. I've tried remaking the bootDrive multiple times. I've tried formating the Drive. An observation maybe worth noting is that I've used this USB drive to install Windows in the past. Maybe this could affect the internal file system or something (though I have formated it and changed the files system in multiple trys)

I could upgrade to 16.04, without reinstalling, but kind of the whole point of reinstalling would be to have a fresh start with my graphics card to install its drivers on a clean slate.

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question in this other question

[Ubuntu 16.04 final not booting from stick: gfxboot.c32: not a COM32R image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760406/ubuntu-16-04-final-not-booting-from-stick-gfxboot-c32-not-a-com32r-image)

Apparently the secrete was to TRY Ubuntu rather than install it, then from within the Try session actually install it.

This is quite a workaround, I'm curious as to what was actually happening  in the first place.