# ubuntu 18.04 live usb boot problem upon installation attempt

Tags: boot, 18.04, usb, lubuntu

I am trying to do a fresh install of lubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad x220 machine. Last running distro was Linux Mint. The usb live stick does not boot correctly, after following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760406/ubuntu-16-04-final-not-booting-from-stick-gfxboot-c32-not-a-com32r-image) solution a lubuntu screen appears. After a few minutes however, I get an error again where this screen appears:

[image: error message]

Usb live sticks were created with

1. the previous system (Mint) on the same machine
2. startup-disk creator on a different machine (ubuntu 14.04)
3. with my neighbours mac following [this](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0) tutorial

virtually all BIOS options, which worked for other users have been tried out. Nothing changes. I tried all of the three USB-ports. I always get the same error screen.

I feel helpless, hope somebody can help.

update: tried with another USB-stick. Still not working. This time however, the loading screen is stuck in a loop (waited for about half an hour)

Comment: 1. Did you check with **`md5sum`**, that the iso file was downloaded correctly? 2. Have you tried with a cloning tool, for example **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or [**`mkusb`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: I got the .iso file from here: https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ How do I compare this to the output of md5sum? I have not tried a cloning tool. Hoping for my neighbour to find another USB-stick (He's sorting through his entire apartment :D

Comment: See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) where there are links to relevant help pages. You find a file named MD5SUMS and you run `md5sum name-of-file.iso` and compare the result with that in the file named MD5SUMS for your particular iso file.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I remember having done this in the past, but where is the file MD5SUMS for my .iso on their website?

Comment: The file `MD5SUMS`  is among the other files. Use the link in the link in my previous comment or directly via this link: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04.1/release/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04.1/release/). 18.04.1 is much better than 18.04.1, so be sure to get that iso file for 64-bits, `lubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: Even if I have an i3?

Comment: better than 18.10 is that?

Comment: Yes, I think so, except for some brand new computers (where you may need the newer hardware drivers, that come with the newer version and its linux kernel), because 1. 18.04.1 LTS has long time support for 3 years (until April 2021), while 18.10 has only 9 months support (until July 1019); 2. The 18.04.1 LTS iso files are more debugged and polished than any 9 month iso file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89355/discussion-between-sudodus-and-michael).

Comment: fyi:  lubuntu.net is a FAN site & not the official Lubuntu site. The official Lubuntu [download] page is https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ but if you're unsure, go to Ubuntu's (official flavor) site https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours