# Making an Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit bootable USB drive using the startup disk creator utility on an Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit computer

Tags: 12.04, 16.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, startup-disk-creator

I made a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit USB drive using the startup disk creator utility on an Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit computer. The final message of the startup disk creator utility said that the bootable drive is successfully created and I can use it.
When I boot my other 64 bit computer using this Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit USB drive I get the following message:
[image]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Although the problem is same, I'll still not delete my question because I thought I got the "error" by creating the bootable drive on a 32 bit system. The moderators can mark it duplicate if they wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is already answered in an other issue.

[Ubuntu 14.04 LTS live USB boot error (gfxboot.c32:not a valid COM32R image)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486602/ubuntu-14-04-lts-live-usb-boot-error-gfxboot-c32not-a-valid-com32r-image)

Comment: Thank you.  Although the problem is same, I'll still not delete my question because I thought I got the "error" by creating the bootable drive on a 32 bit system. The moderators can mark it duplicate if they wish.