# can't boot 16.04.1 from usb disk

Tags: boot

after creating a startup usb disk Booting 16.04.1 I get error:
"gfxboot.c32 not a com32r image".
how do I get a valid image?

Comment: see if this helps: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249701

Comment: use rufus works great for windows. linux uses image writer and user disks program to see if your image is bootable

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486602/ubuntu-14-04-lts-live-usb-boot-error-gfxboot-c32not-a-valid-com32r-image?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

First, I would make sure that you are downloading the installer that matches your computer's architecture. For example, if your computer uses 64-bit, then download the amd64 version of Ubuntu. If your computer is 32-bit, then make sure you download the i386 version of Ubuntu. In windows, you can check this in your System properties. (Open Windows Explorer, right click "My Computer", click "System Properties").

If that does not solve your problem, then try using a different tool to make the live usb. Switch to UNetBootin or Rufus. If you are on a mac, then it will take more research and it is not as easy to make the usb.

It may also be worth it to make sure that your download integrity was not compromised. Verify the checksum after you download it.

Answer (score 0):

`gfxboot.c32 not a com32r image` is caused by a known bug. Try another tool,

- in Windows: **Rufus** or **Win32 Disk Imager**
- in Ubuntu and other linux distros: **mkusb** according to this link

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

These tools work from and to different versions of Windows and Ubuntu.